# SailsJS 1.x UpdatedAt, CreatedAt UTC

Tags: javascript, time, sails.js

Is there a good way to keep the automated createdAt and updatedAt, but also have them use UTC?

I've also noticed in Express/Sails it seems the javascript wants to fight conversions and convert things back to local time(though that is a separate issue).

The work around I used to use was to disable these properties and manually set them in onBeforeUpdate and onBeforeCreate but when you get a lot of models this becomes tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting process.env.TZ = 'UTC'; //whatever timezone you want

in config/bootstrap.js

Comment: I have been unable to test this. Although I had seen this response on similar posts, I just didn't know if it would apply to sails or if Express just automatically looks for that variable and knows. But I will be able to test this in the next couple of days!

Comment: I don't think this worked. Still outputting my local time zone.